# C: Считывание строк

Tags: c, строки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему при таком формате ввода строки, она считывается только до первого пробела?

```
    char str[255];

    puts("Enter polynom: ");
    scanf("%s", str);
```

```
Input:
Enter polynom: 
2x2 + 1x1 + 2

Output
strlen = 3
2x2
```

И как это исправить?

Comment: Почему не `fgets`?

Comment: Потому что так велит [стандарт](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)... Исправить - читать не слово, а строку - [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).